# event handler, broken page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

The page should output and execute a temperature converter...

However,
While I'm wanting to test my program, I keep running into this a blank page type error...
can someone kind of proof read this, because I don't know what I'm missing.

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };


var convertTemp = function(){
    var f;
    var c;
    if($("to_Celsius").checked){
        f = parseFloat($("degrees_entered").value);
        if(isNaN(f)){
            alert("please type in a value ");
        }
        else{
            c = (f-32) * 5/9;
            $("degrees_computed").value = c.toFixed(0);
        }
    }
    else{
        c = parseFloat($("degrees_entered").value);
        if(isNaN(c)){
            alert("you must enter a valid number for degrees.");
        }
        else{
            f = c * 9/5 + 32;
            $("degrees_computed").value = f.toFixed(0);
        }
    }
};

var toFahrenheit = function(){
    $("degree_label_1").firstChild.nodeValue = "Enter C degrees:";
    $("degree_label_2").firstChild.nodeValue = "Degrees F";
    clearTextBoxes();
    $("degrees_entered").focus();
};

var toCelsius = function(){
    $("degree_label_1").firstChild.nodeValue = "Enter F degrees: ";
    $("degree_label_2").firstChild.nodeValue = "Degrees C: ";
    clearTextBoxes();
    $("degrees_entered").focus();
};

var clearTextBoxes = function(){
    $("degrees_entered").value = "";
    $("degrees_computed").value = "";
};

window.onload = function(){
    $("convert").onclick = convertTemp;
    $("to_Celsius").onclick != toCelsius;
    $("to_Fahrenheit").onclick = toFahrenheit;
    $("degrees_entered").focus();
};
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 450px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
h1 {
 color: blue;
 margin: 0 0 .5em;
}
main {
    padding: 1em 2em;
}
label {
 float: left;
    width: 10em;
 margin-right: 1em;
    
}
input {
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
#convert {
 width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Convert Temperatures</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="convert_temp.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <h1>Convert temperatures</h1>    
            <input type="radio" name="conversion_type" id="to_celsius" checked>Fahrenheit to Celsius<br>
            <input type="radio" name="conversion_type" id="to_fahrenheit">Celsius to Fahrenheit<br><br>
            <label id="degree_label_1">Enter F degrees:</label>
            <input type="text" id="degrees_entered" ><br>
            <label id="degree_label_2">Degrees Celsius:</label>
            <input type="text" id="degrees_computed" disabled><br>
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="button" id="convert" value="Convert" /><br>   
        </main>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

toCelcius != toCelsius ?

Is that it? A silly typo?  The rest looks fine... also watch casing. In your JS you have `to_Celsius`... but in the html... `to_celcius`... bad habit for sure

Answer (score 0):

Some issues I verified:

1. in the line `if($("to_Celsius").checked){` you refer to `to_Celsius` id, but it should be `to_celsius` (lowercase);
2. in the lines:

   ```
   $("to_Celsius").onclick = toCelsius;
   $("to_Fahrenheit").onclick = toFahrenheit;
   ```

   Same thing. Replace both the `id` with `to_celsius` and `to_fahrenheit`.
3. in this line `var toCelcius = function(){`, the function is named `toCelcius`. Just rename it to `toCelsius` (with **s**).

#### Working code: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/p8w111ms/